# MSAccess SQL query to find latest date >180 in past

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, self-join, isnull

I am trying to write an sql query on a table which will give me the result similar to the Formula_Based sheet in the below link [see Formula_Based sheet in sample.xlsx]:

[Sample.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByraEKowSDpWdUtPbkJlei1JNjQ)

The query i have managed to write is :

```
SELECT x.[CTY], x.[CAT], x.[OWN], x.[BRD], x.[EXT], x.[appeared date], y.[appeared date], x.[ATTR], y.[ATTR]
    FROM TEMP AS x 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT  [CTY], [CAT], [OWN], [BRD], [EXT], [appeared date], MIN([appeared date]),[ATTR]
    FROM TEMP 
    GROUP BY [CTY], [CAT], [OWN], [BRD], [EXT], [appeared date],[ATTR]
    ) AS y 
    ON 
    (
    x.[CAT]=y.[CAT]
    AND x.[CTY]=y.[CTY]
    AND x.[OWN]=y.[OWN]
    AND x.[BRD]=y.[BRD]
    AND x.[EXT]=y.[EXT]
    AND x.[appeared date] > y.[appeared date]
    AND x.[appeared date] - y.[appeared date]>180 
    )
    GROUP BY x.[CTY], x.[CAT], x.[OWN], x.[BRD], x.[EXT], x.[appeared date],y.[appeared date],x.[ATTR],y.[ATTR]
    HAVING y.[ATTR]="NEW"
```

The Data has more columns but i have shown only the most required columns. The Data is sorted on following columns sequence ie. CTY, CAT, OWN, BRD, EXT, APPEARED DATE. What i am trying to find is whether same product (having the same CTY, CAT, OWN, BRD, EXT, APPEARED DATE) was launched 180 or more in the past. So i need a Previous Date column (>180 column) which will show me the earliest date >180 in the past for ATTR = 'NEW'.

I have done a LEFT JOIN inorder to get all the rows of the table (32 rows but getting only 25). I am not able to add NULL where the Previous dates cannot be determined. [See Query_Based sheet in Sample.xlsx).

How to add blanks or NULL to y.[appeared date] column (i.e. previous date column)? Is there a better and efficient way to write this query?

P.S: I run the query in MSAccess.

Comment: Technically, the question should not say "(having the same CTY, CAT, OWN, BRD, EXT, APPEARED DATE) launched 180 or more..." since it's not possible to have the same APPEARED DATE and be launched at a different times.  It should say "(having the same CTY, CAT, OWN, BRD, EXT) launched 180 or more..."

Comment: The text says "launched 180 or more" which implies >= 180 not just >180.  Otherwise it should say "launched more than 180".  So which is it?  BTW, perhaps "days" is implied but as I was taught and have always passed on to my students--always include the units. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of brevity, I will simply refer to the group of columns [CTY], [CAT], [OWN], [BRD], [EXT] as the "key".

The original query and the other answer are making a fundamental selection error:  The inner query is selecting *only one date per key*, namely `MIN([appeared date])`, yet the most recent "launch" date (> 180 days) varies with different values of `[appeared date]` for the same key.  The subquery must therefore apply the date condition prior to selecting the most recent launch date.  In other words, the condition "> 180 days" must be applied before the `Max([appeared date])` expression and corresponding grouping.  (FYI:  Because join conditions are applied before aggregate operations, it is sufficient to have both in the same query and still satisfy the correct application order.)

The launch date is also qualified by the condition `[Attr] = "New"`.  This must be applied in its own subquery for at least two reasons:

1. If the condition `TEMP.[Attr] = "New"` were applied in the same query (e.g. in a WHERE clause), that would exclude the possibility of returning Null rows in a left-join, so the end result would only include rows with non-null "launch dates >180 days".  That's the cause of the 25 rows instead of the full 32 in the attempts so far.
2. Access requires each join operation to include columns from each table, so something like `T1.[Attr] = "New"` is not allowed.  There are tricks to circumvent this restriction, but a separate subquery is still required for the previous reason and it's just as simple to add the condition to the WHERE clause rather than mess further with the join.

Finally, here is the complete SQL query:

```
    SELECT TEMP.CTY, TEMP.CAT, TEMP.OWN, TEMP.BRD, TEMP.EXT,
        TEMP.[Appeared date], TEMP.ATTR, GT180.[GT180 date],
        (TEMP.[Appeared date]-[GT180 date]) AS diff_h
    FROM TEMP 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT T2.CTY, T2.CAT, T2.OWN, T2.BRD, T2.EXT,
             T2.[Appeared date], Max(News.[Appeared date]) AS [GT180 Date]
         FROM TEMP AS T2
             LEFT JOIN
                 (SELECT T1.CTY, T1.CAT, T1.OWN, T1.BRD, T1.EXT, T1.[Appeared date], T1.ATTR 
                  FROM TEMP AS T1
                  WHERE (T1.ATTR="New")) AS News
             ON (News.[Appeared date]<=T2.[Appeared date]-180) 
                 AND (T2.CTY = News.CTY) AND (T2.CAT = News.CAT)
                 AND (T2.OWN = News.OWN) AND (T2.BRD = News.BRD) AND (T2.EXT = News.EXT)
             GROUP BY T2.CTY, T2.CAT, T2.OWN, T2.BRD, T2.EXT, T2.[Appeared date])  AS GT180
        ON (TEMP.[Appeared date] = GT180.[Appeared date]) 
            AND (TEMP.EXT = GT180.EXT) AND (TEMP.BRD = GT180.BRD) AND (TEMP.OWN = GT180.OWN) 
            AND (TEMP.CAT = GT180.CAT) AND (TEMP.CTY = GT180.CTY);
```

Note: The table [Temp] is aliased differently in each subquery to avoid any possible problem with Access interpreting the references to the same table in different subqueries.

Here's an alternative but equivalent query using a parameterized subquery:

```
SELECT TEMP.CTY, TEMP.CAT, TEMP.OWN, TEMP.BRD, TEMP.EXT, 
    TEMP.[Appeared date], TEMP.ATTR, 
    (SELECT Max([Appeared Date]) AS [GT180 Date] 
     FROM TEMP AS T1
     WHERE ((T1.CTY=[TEMP].[CTY]) AND (T1.CAT=[TEMP].[CAT]) AND (T1.OWN=[TEMP].[OWN]) 
        AND (T1.BRD=[TEMP].[BRD]) AND (T1.EXT=[TEMP].[EXT]) 
        AND (T1.[Appeared date] < [TEMP].[Appeared Date]-180) AND (T1.ATTR="New"))
    ) AS [GT180 Date],
    [Appeared date]-[GT180 Date] AS diff_h
FROM TEMP;
```

Comment: Yes... C Perkins has meshed out the details here.  Getting the sub-queries right was the challenge with this problem.  Since I was only trying to point the way and didn't have time to get to the proper detail level, I'll delete my response.  Good job! :)

Comment: @abraxascarab i found your responses quite informative, so don't know why you deleted them. But a BIG THANK YOU for helping out.